# Will the original object get deleted if I return a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I want to do something like this:

```
unique_ptr<MyObj> MyFunc() {
  MyObj* ptr = new MyObj();
  ...
  return unique_ptr<MyObj>(ptr);
}

unique_ptr<MyObj> value = MyFunc();
```

But I'm unsure if the object will be deleted when the temporary value was destructed after the function returns. If so, how should I implement correctly a function that returns a `unique_ptr`?

Answer (score 10):

No, the object will not be deleted when function scope ends. This is because move constructor of `unique_ptr` will 'move' the ownership semantics to the new `unique_ptr` object, and destruction of the old `unique_ptr` will not cause deletion of the allocated object.

**Note**: This is not the right way of doing this. If there is an exception thrown between the point of memory allocation and `unique_ptr<>` creation you will have a memory leak.

Comment: The note regarding exception safety is nice

Comment: The managed raw pointer will eventually be deleted though, via the moved from unique pointer, so the function does not create a memory leak. Agree with the note, upvoted!

Answer (score 3):

Although the code can compile and work, it is the best to work with `std::make_unique` directly:

```
return std::make_unique<T>(/* your arguments*/);
```

your snippet can create some problems such as:

1. `new` can throw `std::bad_alloc` if no memory available
2. `MyObj` can throw an exception
3. `ptr` can get lost in the way until it is assigned to the `unique_ptr`

Comment: First two are usually not a problem.

Comment: For writers of the functions similar in nature to Func().

Comment: @SergeyA There is no reason to not note it down though. Good answer. +1

Comment: @DavidHaim, bad_allocs or object constructors throwing exceptions are not a thing factory-style functions (func() is obviously a factory) are worrying about.

Comment: @SergeyA you are making some vast assumptions here.

Comment: Whether you use new or make_unique, you will *still* have to handle the exception should it be thrown. So no point in using it here.

Comment: ...except that when you use make_unique all of three are encapsulated in one line of code instead being spread  throughat the code, that was my point

Comment: Points 1 and 2 can still happen when you use `std::make_unique`. The results are the same in both cases. The difference is only in 3 and it prevents the leak if the object is fully constructed.

Answer (score 1):

The way to allocate the pointer is [std::make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique). There are similar functions for the other types of smart pointers as well, e.g. [std::make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared).

If you want to return it from a function, you should use std::move, since unique_ptrs don't like to be copied.

Return it like this: `return std::move(ptr);`

Comment: When I `return std::move(ptr)`, should the return type be just `unique_ptr<MyObj>` or `&&unique_ptr<MyObj>` instead? I've never seen the latter before, but it seems that in move semantics we need a double reference?

Comment: The best way to allocate a unique ptr may be `std::make_unique` but that has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: When you return a unique_ptr you don't need to use std::move. The code above works as designed.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing goes wrong, your code should work; the original object will be created within the `MyFunc` function and its ownership will be transferred back to the caller.  However, the best way to create a `std::unique_ptr` is with `std::create_unique` (to avoid possible leaks upon intervening error conditions).  You can verify that this happens correctly with either a debugger or some console output; My expansion/modification of your code (shown below) produces the following output, verifying that only one object is created and it is destroyed at the end of `main`):

```
Created
999
Destroyed
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class MyObj
{
public:
  MyObj( int v )
  : value( v )
  {
    std::cout << "Created" << std::endl;
  }

  ~MyObj()
  {
    std::cout << "Destroyed" << std::endl;
  }

  int value;
};

std::unique_ptr<MyObj> MyFunc()
{
  auto ptr = std::make_unique<MyObj>( 999 );

  // ...do other stuff here?...

  // return std::move( ptr );  // Loki Astari says move() is unnecessary
  return ptr;
}

int main()
{
  auto p = MyFunc();
  std::cout << p->value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @LokiAstari Thanks!  Removed.  (It's been a while for me; I've been off in Python land for a year!)